# Can I create a unique ID variable given a set of data in a column?

Tags: r, primary-key

I have a set of id variables that contains letters and numbers. I want to generate a unique numerical ID for those variables since the program that I am working with only accepts numeric data.

There are multiple cases (students) per classroom but each classroom has a unique id.

The goal is to replace each unique alphanumeric class IDs with a unique numeric version. My data set has about 18000 unique class IDs and over unique 185000 students.

Can this be done using R?

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(StuID=c("112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117"), CLASSID=c("123B542 ", "123B542", "458Z84 ", "458Z84 ", "760E53", "760E53"))
```

Desired Output

```
df <-(stuID= c("112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117"),CLASSID=c("123B542 ", "123B542", "458Z84 ", "458Z84 ", "760E53", "760E53"), NewID= c("12", "12", "13" "13", "14", "14"))
```

I am not sure where to start with this code. I tried doing it manually but I have a data set with about over 18K unique ClassIDs.

Comment: If it has to be unique then we need  more information.  "121314" is one six-digit number out of a set of 10^6 = 1,000,000 numbers but it's only going to be unique if no other id-set is mapped to 121314 by your function / code.  For example any hash function is allowed to have collisions so it's not unique.  What parts of a c make it unique?  (Edit your question to make this clear, don't answer in comments)

Comment: What context is this in? SQL? NoSQL? How big can the number be? How large can the input values be? There's a lot of unanswered questions here. We need to know the boundary conditions for any possible solution.

Comment: Hey Tadman, thanks for responding. I am working in R. Sorry about that omission. I am trying to replace the alphanumeric class IDs with a numeric version.

Comment: Can you edit again to explain your mapping scheme?  The logic behind mapping "760E53" to "14" instead of "76" is not obvious to me.

Comment: Hey Dave, 14 is an arbitrary number. I understand what you are saying but some of the classids have the same first 6 digits before a different letter (i.e., 234567R101, 234567P101). Just want each to be unique without using the old info.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am understanding, you want each unique `CLASSID` group to have a corresponding numerical ID. Because your program only accepts numerical data, this will allow you to differentiate between classrooms.

In your example code, there were some inconsistencies with spacing in your `CLASSID` variables. For example, the first instance of `123B542` had a space after it while the second did not. I did not know if that was intentional and assumed you had not meant to put the space there. If that was intentional (and those two class IDs are assumed to be the same), I would clean up the spaces using:

```
df$CLASSID = gsub(" ", "", df$CLASSID)
```

For your actual question, if you just want to give an arbitrary number to each `CLASSID` by grouping, you can use `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[, NewID := .GRP, by = CLASSID]
```

This gives the following output:

```
StuID CLASSID NewID
112 123B542     1
113 123B542     1
114  458Z84     2
115  458Z84     2
116  760E53     3
117  760E53     3
```

Comment: Hey sumshyftw, thanks for your response. The space was not supposed to be there. You have answered my question. I appreciate that.

Comment: I tried it but I am getting an error with the code you provided. Error is: could not find function setDT

Comment: You need to make sure you have `data.table` installed. Install it with `install.packages("data.table")` and load it with `library(data.table)`

Comment: Got you!! Thanks

Comment: @JonteMyers -  If you get it working, don't forget to accept and up-vote this answer.

Comment: @Dave S. It worked and I attempted to upvote but got a message that my vote would not change the publicly displayed posted score

Answer (score 0):

Using only base R (no package requiered):

```
class_ids <- unique(df$CLASSID)
df$NewID <- match(df$CLASSID, class_ids)
df
  StuID CLASSID NewID
1   112 123B542     1
2   113 123B542     1
3   114  458Z84     2
4   115  458Z84     2
5   116  760E53     3
6   117  760E53     3
```

*Data*

```
df <- data.frame(
  StuID=c("112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117"), 
  CLASSID=c("123B542", "123B542", "458Z84", "458Z84", "760E53", "760E53")
)
```